# Using Objective C API in Macro to Log in static lib

Tags: ios, objective-c, command-line-arguments, preprocessor-directive

I would like to do something like this, but having error on the first 'if'.

```
#if ([[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments] containsObject:@"-com.myproj.MyLibDebug"])
#define DLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define DLog(...) /* */
#endif
```

How can I use it using macro? is it possible to write such expression in Objective C?

or doing something more advanced, such that 
get the next value of `-com.myproj.MyLibDebug` in arguments array and then set the debug log level to 4 or 8 depending on the value.

The arguments passed from build configuration (scheme) is

```
-com.myproj.MyLibDebug 4
```

Comment: Any negative vote should be explained.

Answer (score 1):

I would go the other way around and base the define on the if() result.

```
#define DLog(fmt, ...) { if ([[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments] containsObject:@"-com.myproj.MyLibDebug"]) {\
....\
} else {\
}
```

The `#if` is macro based, it can't use dynamic values

Comment: ... so the issue is what?  Mixing compile time and runtime elements?  Also would you care to comment on the expense incurred with that macro?

Comment: Yes, the issue is that macros are evaluated at compilation time, not at run time, so the evaluation of the arguments array can't take place. As for complexity/time expense, the preprocessor will change every occurence of `DLog()` with the `if() {}` block. I'm not an expert on the macro subject, though.

Comment: Thanks. This seems better or will work. But to get the values, I better have a new Logger class which will decode and use NSLog. The problem with this then I can print out message, but loose the __LINE__  and __FILE__ macro. Not it?

Comment: You could use a macro that will use `_LINE_` and `_FILE_` as parameters. I suggest you take a look at cocoalumberjack to handle the logging part, i found it very useful and customizable.

Answer (score 0):

I could  not use MACRO for this kind of logging, rather have my own class to log it, since I have to decode the runtime logLevel from the arguments passed on launching. Here is my class.

### Header file.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, IDCLogFlag) {
    IDCLogFlagError     = (1 << 0),
    IDCLogFlagWarning   = (1 << 1),
    IDCLogFlagInfo      = (1 << 2),
    IDCLogFlagDebug     = (1 << 3),
    IDCLogFlagVerbose   = (1 << 4)
};

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, IDCLogLevel) {
    IDCLogLevelOff      = 0,
    IDCLogLevelError    = IDCLogFlagError,
    IDCLogLevelWarning  = IDCLogFlagError | IDCLogFlagWarning,
    IDCLogLevelInfo     = IDCLogLevelWarning | IDCLogFlagInfo,
    IDCLogLevelDebug    = IDCLogLevelInfo | IDCLogFlagDebug,
    IDCLogLevelVerbose  = IDCLogLevelDebug | IDCLogFlagVerbose,
    IDCLogLevelAll      = NSUIntegerMax
};

@interface IDCLogger : NSObject

/** Programmatically set the log level.*/
+ (void)setLogLevel:(int)l;

+(void)error:(NSString *)format, ... ;
+(void)warn:(NSString *)format, ... ;
+(void)info:(NSString *)format, ... ;
+(void)debug:(NSString *)format, ... ;
+(void)verbose:(NSString *)format, ... ;

@end
```

### .m file

```
#import "IDCLogger.h"

static NSUInteger logLevel = IDCLogLevelError;

/** This argument should be passed from XCode's build scheme configuration option, Arguments passed on launch */
static const NSString *kIdcLogLevelArgument = @"-com.yourcompany.IDCLogLevel";

@implementation IDCLogger

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {
    static id sharedInstance = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}

+(void)initialize
{
    NSArray *arguments = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments];
    NSUInteger value = 1;
    if ([arguments containsObject:kIdcLogLevelArgument]) {
        NSUInteger index = [arguments indexOfObject:kIdcLogLevelArgument];
        if (arguments.count > index) {
            NSString *valueStr = [arguments objectAtIndex:index + 1];
            NSCharacterSet* notDigits = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];
            if ([valueStr rangeOfCharacterFromSet:notDigits].location == NSNotFound)
            {
                value = [valueStr integerValue];
            }
        }
    }

    logLevel = value;

//  NSUInteger exp = 0;
//  if (value > 0) {
//      exp = log2(value) + 1;
//  }
//  logLevel = pow(2, exp);
//  NSLog(@"logLevel = %lu", (unsigned long)logLevel);
}

+ (void)setLogLevel:(int)l
{
    logLevel = l;
    NSLog(@"[%@] Log level set to: %i", [self class], l);
}

+(void)error:(NSString *)format, ... {
    if (logLevel >= IDCLogLevelError) {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, format);
        [[self sharedInstance] logFormat:format withParameters:args];
        va_end(args);
    }
}

+(void)warn:(NSString *)format, ... {
    if (logLevel >= IDCLogLevelWarning) {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, format);
        [[self sharedInstance] logFormat:format withParameters:args];
        va_end(args);
    }
}

+(void)info:(NSString *)format, ... {
    if (logLevel >= IDCLogLevelInfo) {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, format);
        [[self sharedInstance] logFormat:format withParameters:args];
        va_end(args);
    }
}

+(void)debug:(NSString *)format, ... {
    if (logLevel >= IDCLogLevelDebug) {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, format);
        [[self sharedInstance] logFormat:format withParameters:args];
        va_end(args);
    }
}

+(void)verbose:(NSString *)format, ... {
    if (logLevel >= IDCLogLevelVerbose) {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, format);
        [[self sharedInstance] logFormat:format withParameters:args];
        va_end(args);
    }
}

/** log the message formatted with status*/
-(void) log:(NSString*)format, ...
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    va_end(args);
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:args];
    NSLog(@"%@", str);
    [str release];
}

-(void) logFormat:(NSString *)format withParameters:(va_list)valist
{
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:valist];
    NSLog(@"%@", str);
    [str release];
}

@end
```

### Test code

```
- (void)testLogger
{
    [IDCLogger error:@"Error"];
    [IDCLogger warn:@"Warning"];
    [IDCLogger info:@"Info"];
    [IDCLogger debug:@"Debug"];
    [IDCLogger verbose:@"Verbose"];

    NSDate *d = [NSDate date];
    int i = 123;
    [IDCLogger error:@"Error with params. %i, %@", i, d];
    [IDCLogger warn:@"Warning with params. %i, %@", i, d];
    [IDCLogger info:@"Info with params. %i, %@", i, d];
    [IDCLogger debug:@"Debug with params. %i, %@", i, d];
    [IDCLogger verbose:@"verbose with params. %i, %@", i, d];

    [IDCLogger setLogLevel:0]; // no logging
    [IDCLogger error:@"Error with params. %i, %@", i, d];
    [IDCLogger warn:@"Warning with params. %i, %@", i, d];
    [IDCLogger info:@"Info with params. %i, %@", i, d];
    [IDCLogger debug:@"Debug with params. %i, %@", i, d];
    [IDCLogger verbose:@"verbose with params. %i, %@", i, d];

    [IDCLogger setLogLevel:UINT_MAX]; // All logging
    [IDCLogger error:@"Error with params. %i, %@", i, d];
    [IDCLogger warn:@"Warning with params. %i, %@", i, d];
    [IDCLogger info:@"Info with params. %i, %@", i, d];
    [IDCLogger debug:@"Debug with params. %i, %@", i, d];
    [IDCLogger verbose:@"verbose with params. %i, %@", i, d];

    [IDCLogger setLogLevel:IDCLogLevelDebug]; // value = 15, error, warn, info and debug log
    [IDCLogger error:@"Error with params. %i, %@", i, d];
    [IDCLogger warn:@"Warning with params. %i, %@", i, d];
    [IDCLogger info:@"Info with params. %i, %@", i, d];
    [IDCLogger debug:@"Debug with params. %i, %@", i, d];
    [IDCLogger verbose:@"verbose with params. %i, %@", i, d];
}
```